# Name of a DB2 restoration of the same database at a different time

Tags: db2, restore, db2-luw

Each time I perform a **restore** of the same database, but at a different time (different version recoveries), a CXXXXXXX directory is created in the archive log directory. This is normal, but I would like to know the right term of that new db branch.  How is it called in **db2**?

- a fork
- a branch
- an incarnation

This is like a split brain but not in HADR, but when performing restores in the same machine.

Comment: It looks like a Google search on 'db2 luw point in time recovery' should get you to the information with a bit more diligence than I've got at this time of night.  The statement is RECOVER DATABASE.  The manual page for the statement doesn't mention the directory.  No doubt, if you find the admin guide where RECOVER DATABASE is described, you'll find the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called *Log Chains*.  Each log chain is associated with a particular database *seed*.  When you perform point in time recovery DB2 increments the database seed.